# How to enable/disable click event for div-Jquery

Tags: jquery, click, bind, tic-tac-toe

I'm building a tic tac toe game and have removed the click event for the squares once the game is over with for example:

```
    $("#square1").off("click");
```

but then when I try to enabke the click event after I have pressed a reset button with for eample 
        $("#square1").on("click");
It doesn't enable the click event. How can I enable the click event.

Comment: Can you provide a live example in for example CodePen or JsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$el = $('.el');
$el.click(function(){
$this = $(this);

  if($this.hasClass('ready')){
  // do some stuff.
  }

$this.removeClass('ready');
});

$('#reset').click(function(){
$el.addClass('ready');
});
```

```css
div{
margin:9px;
}
.el:after{
content:'already clicked';
width:9em;
padding:9px;
background-color:#f99;
opacity:0.6;
display:table-cell;
}
#reset, .el{
cursor:pointer;
}
.ready:after{
content:'click here';
opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='ready el'></div>
<div class='ready el'></div>
<div class='ready el'></div>
<a id='reset'>Reset</a>
```